# Mongoose and mongoDB - duplicate key error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I'm trying to use MongoDB and mongoose for my little conversation app in where each user is having it's own collection but I'm getting an error when saving a new conversation:

**ERROR: MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: chat.privatemessages.$*id*  dup key: { : ObjectId('54f1a39ff467833f7e794636') }**

My Schema:

```
    var chatPrivateMessagesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: String,
    with:[{
        conversation_with: String,
        messages:[{
            text:String,
            created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
        }]
    }]
});

var PrivateMessages = mongoose.model('PrivateMessages', chatPrivateMessagesSchema);
```

Method for saving new conversation:

```
socket.on ('chat', function (from, to, message, callback) {
    PrivateMessages.find ({}, function (err, users) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].user == from) {
                var newPrivateMsg = new PrivateMessages ({_id: users[i]._id}, {
                    with: [{
                        conversation_with: to, //if conversation with "to" user does not exist create a new entry
                        messages: [{
                            text: message, //append a new message 
                            created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
                        }]
                    }]
                });
                newPrivateMsg.save (function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So basically the output I'm looking for should be something like this?

```
{
    "_id": "some id",
    "user": "John",
    "with": [{
        "conversation_with": "Maria",
        "_id": "some id",
        "messages": [{
            "text": "Hellomyfisrtmessage",
            "created": "somedate"
        }, {
            "text": "Secondmessage ",
            "created": "somedate"
        }, {
            "text": "Thirdmessage",
            "created": "somedate"
        }, ]
    }, {
        "conversation_with": "Peter",
        "_id": "some id",
        "messages": [{
                "text": "Hellomyfisrtmessage",
                "created": "somedate"
            }, {
                "text": "Secondmessage ",
                "created": "somedate"
            }, {
                "text": "Third message",
                "created": "some date"
            },

        ]
    }],

}
```

I'm really struggling how to insert a new entry :( Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting every PrivateMessage _id to the user's _id, don't do that!

EDIT:

```
socket.on ('chat', function (from, to, message, callback) {
    PrivateMessages.find ({}, function (err, users) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].user == from) {
                users[i].with.forEach(function(with){
                    if (with.conversation_with === to ){

                        // append new message
                        with.messages.push({
                            text: message,
                            created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
                        })
                    }
                })

                users[i].save (function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @Yuri , but your solution is adding a new entry each time for the same user. I need to keep the same entry for the same user and just  add a new message for that particular person in `conversation_with: to`

Comment: So, your original question involved inserts, but what you actually want is an update, with a possible insert (if it doesn't exist?). I've updated my answer to show you how something like this could be done. But you'll likely have to modify it to include a condition where conversation_with does not match "to" , in which case you'd need to create one. I strongly suggest you simplify your schema, you do not need 2 nested arrays.

Comment: thanks so much @Yuri, this is what I needed. You're amazing. Although, I just realised that the schema might not be a best solution for storing the conversation between two people, as I'm saving only one persons messages, I then need to retrieve both users messages. I need to work on that. But anyway, thanks again.

Comment: btw, do you know of any good suitable schema for conversation between two people?

Comment: Its typically a good idea to simplify as much as possible. As for a conversation between two people, the 'conversation' is really an abstract idea symbolizing a collection of messages between two people, and can easily be modeled using queries. My schema would probably simply be { sender: ObjectId, recipient: ObjectId, message: String }. Where sender/recipient are ObjectId's lining to their respective user id's. Inserts become trivial (just call new and save). To find a conversation by user, just do a query where sender OR recipient == userid, followed by some basic array manipulation.